# Custom Max-Pooling layer for image classification

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification, max-pooling

I want to make a custom pooling layer in a CNN model using keras tensorflow.
[For visual description (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zykum.png)
In the above picture it shows a maxpooling operation on a 4x4 feature map with 2x2 filter and the output is a 2x2 feature map. I want two 2x2 featuremap instead. One is the same as this one and other picks the 2nd largest activation.
I have searched so much, this is what I have found similar to what I am trying. But it is just picking the k maximum for the whole tensor. Anyone, please help me.

```
class KMaxPooling(Layer):
"""
K-max pooling layer that extracts the k-highest activations from a sequence (2nd dimension).
TensorFlow backend.
"""
def __init__(self, k=1, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=3)
    self.k = k

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], (input_shape[2] * self.k))

def call(self, inputs):
    
    # swap last two dimensions since top_k will be applied along the last dimension
    shifted_input = tf.transpose(inputs, [0, 2, 1])
    
    # extract top_k, returns two tensors [values, indices]
    top_k = tf.nn.top_k(shifted_input, k=self.k, sorted=True, name=None)[0]
    
    # return flattened output
    return Flatten()(top_k)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks for the comment, I have rephrased my question and added a picture to explain. Please let me know if you need further explanation.

Comment: You have a mistake in your explanation image ;) (in the 2nd largest activation map you have 70 instead of 100).